# Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Show that $\int_{0}^{1} x^n f(x)dx \rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Idea: I thought of using the Mean value theorem for integrals

It says that if $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are two integrable functions, and if $g(x)$ does not change sign on $[a,b]$.

Then $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x) dx = \alpha\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx$ where $m \le \alpha \le M$ .

Now take $g(x) = x^n$ and the above problem reduces to $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \alpha\int_{0}^{1}x^ndx$.

Now if we evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}x^ndx$ we get $\frac{1}{n+1}$ which whe $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ is taken gives $0$.

Is the approach correct?

Can the integral be evaluated before taking the limit?

Comment: Your approach is correct. You have $m/(n+1)=$   $m\int_0^1x^n\;dx=$ $\int_0^1mx^n\;dx \leq$ $ \int_0^1 f(x)x^n\;dx\leq$ $  \int _0^1M  x^n\; dx=$ $M\int_0^1x^n\;dx$ $=M/(n+1).$ So $m/(n+1)\leq $ $\int_0^1f(x)\;dx \leq $ $ M/(n+1).$

Comment: This is also true if $f$ is just Lebesgue integrable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's simpler than that. $f$ continuous on compact interval implies $|f|\leq M$ for some $M$. Then $$\int_0^1 |x^nf(x)|dx \leq M \int_0^1 x^ndx=\frac{M}{n+1} \rightarrow 0.$$

Comment: With the remark that $\left|\int_0^1 g(x)\,dx\right|\le\int_0^1|g(x)|\,dx$ (+1)

Comment: Indeed ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: thanks .. but is my proof right?

Comment: Yes it looks right

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use the Cauchy Schwarz inequality on the inner product space of
continuous functions with the $L_2[0,1]$ norm.

Let $p_n(x) = x^n$, then $\|p_n\| = {1 \over \sqrt{1+2n}}$ and so
$|\int_0^1 x^n f(x) dx | = | \langle p_n,f\rangle| \le \|p_n\| \|f\|$, and $f$ is continuous implies $f \in L_2[0,1] \implies \|f\| < + \infty,$ hence $\int_0^1 x^n f(x) dx \to 0 $.